# We have two questions about the Fate Accelerated top approach issue. How should we handle this?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

These two questions seem like they're both about fundamentally the same thing:

- [How to avoid players using the same Approaches?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/29690/1204)
- [How do I prevent PCs from spamming their top approach in every situation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/66899/1204)

How should we handle this?

I'm asking meta because I have a conflict of interest here. Usually I'd be inclined to keep the most useful question/answer set open and close the other, but I have my own answer on one of those giving me bias. As a result I wish to excuse myself from the decision making process about what to do, but I do want to bring this to the community's attention so action can be taken.

Comment: Posting as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not sure, but I *thought* mods could merge questions, essentially marking question B as a duplicate but transferring all its answers to question A. If that is, in fact, something the mods can do then we would merely need to decide which question is better phrased, as the answers from both would be preserved.

Comment: @ObliviousSage This is true, yeah.

Comment: One thing to note is that they can't be merged unless one is a duplicate of the other (merge doesn't care which), so they should be nominated for closing as duplicates first. They may not actually be duplicates—they're very similar and might be duplicates, but there are a few notes different in each that might be judged by the community as sufficiently different to not be duplicates. So, first things first!

Answer (score 5):

<sup>*Since nobody else feels like proposing any solutions...*</sup>

**Let's create a new canonical question for this topic and merge both existing questions into it.**

For those unfamiliar with them, [canonical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992/1175868) are questions specifically designed to be the "ideal" (read: most searchable) version of a frequently asked question, so that all the other variations of it can be closed as duplicates.

Per SSD, mods have the power to merge questions; this is kind of like a super close-as-duplicate, which moves all the answers to the closed question over to the unclosed (canonical) question.

Now, certainly a case could be made that we should use one of the existing questions, but they're both somewhat rambling, and I think we can do better. Hence, my suggestion of a canonical question. If you feel that either of the existing questions is close enough to ideal, you're free to downvote this answer and post your own; nobody's feelings will be hurt.